# How To Remove Line in Core Graphics

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, core-graphics

I draw a line using CGContextAddLineToPoint in my app now i want to remove  line from given points how can i do this i am using touches for drawing line

Comment: Plese put some code you have added.

Answer (score 5):

You can erase,

Given the two points, draw the line with same attributes(lineWidth etc.,)  by setting the `CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeClear)`.

Comment: how can i erase the already draw a line in ios map. i have tried this above code. it is not working for me. can u help me?

Comment: @Kannnan, It will erase the lines drawn in the context only.Is the line drawn by you in the context. I don't think it is!.

Comment: ya i have drawn using context only.can u help ma what am did wrong in my code?

Comment: Please see this http://pastie.org/6460938. here the remove value method for erase line code.

Comment: The context you use to remove the drawings and add the drawings are not same. So you will not be able to erase it.

Comment: any idea to remove the line. any code. can u give me some idea?