# How can I erase a line between two CGpoint?

Tags: ios, objective-c, line

[image]

I am creating a line in ipad as user touch the screen and and drag the finger. Problem is line is creating on every point in by (touchMoved:) we we drag it. But in last it should only one not many. How can I erase or remove last line after created new one? Here is my code:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(ArrowDraw==YES){
        NSLog(@"ArrowDrawing");
        if ([[event allTouches]count]==1){
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:FullImageView];
            UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
            [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,      self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
            CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);
            CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
            CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
            CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 1 );
            CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), red, green, blue, 1.0);
            CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),kCGBlendModeNormal);
            CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
            self.tempDrawImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
            [self.tempDrawImage setAlpha:opacity];
            UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
            //firstPoint = currentPoint;
            NSLog(@"TouchMoving x=%f y=%f",firstPoint.x,firstPoint.y);
        }
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.FullImageView.frame.size);
        [self.FullImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0];
        [self.tempDrawImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:opacity];
        self.FullImageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        self.tempDrawImage.hidden=YES;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601691/how-to-remove-line-in-core-graphics

Comment: I like suppose, that you only draw "one" single line. Move or remove this line by gesturs like paning or pinching.

Comment: @thomas i want to create a line which is movable and dragable to last point position. but line is created every time and i am not finding any solution to erase last one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key is to not update the image, but rather just draw the arrow on top of the image. Then replace the arrow with another as the `touchesMoved` come in.

For example, I might use the QuartzCore.framework by adding it to your target's "Link Binary With Libraries" and add the following line to the start of your .m:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```

Then you can define a new ivar for your `CAShapeLayer`:

```
CAShapeLayer *shapeLayer;
```

Finally, then update your `touchesMoved` to something like:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (ArrowDraw==YES){
        if ([[event allTouches]count]==1) {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:FullImageView];

            if (!shapeLayer)
            {
                shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
                shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
                shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
                shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
                [FullImageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
            }
            UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
            [path moveToPoint:firstPoint];
            [path addLineToPoint:currentPoint];
            shapeLayer.path = [path CGPath];
        }
    }
}
```

You can modify that `UIBezierPath` to include the arrowhead if you need that, too, for example:

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    if (ArrowDraw==YES){
        if ([[event allTouches]count]==1) {
            UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
            CGPoint currentPoint = [touch locationInView:FullImageView];

            if (!shapeLayer) {
                [self createShapeLayer];
            }

            shapeLayer.path = [[self arrowPathFrom:firstPoint to:currentPoint arrowheadSize:10.0] CGPath];
        }
    }
}

- (void)createShapeLayer
{
    shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
    shapeLayer.lineWidth = 1;
    shapeLayer.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
    shapeLayer.fillColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
    [FullImageView.layer addSublayer:shapeLayer];
}

- (UIBezierPath *)arrowPathFrom:(CGPoint)start to:(CGPoint)end arrowheadSize:(CGFloat)arrowheadSize
{
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path moveToPoint:start];
    [path addLineToPoint:end];

    // add arrowhead

    CGFloat angle = atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x) + M_PI * 3.0 / 4.0;
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cos(angle) * arrowheadSize + end.x, sin(angle) * arrowheadSize + end.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:end];
    angle = atan2(end.y - start.y, end.x - start.x) - M_PI * 3.0 / 4.0;
    [path addLineToPoint:CGPointMake(cos(angle) * arrowheadSize + end.x, sin(angle) * arrowheadSize + end.y)];
    [path addLineToPoint:end];

    return path;
}
```

Comment: its working fine but its creating only one arrow. means when i created a arrow and want to add another. its removes first one and make other.

Comment: @Mohittomar You could `nil` the `shapeLayer` variable in `touchedEnded`. That would let you draw multiple lines. You would probably also save the start and ending point for your arrow in your model, too (but that's unrelated to your question).

Comment: apology from my heart bro.